# Mac Debug Step Into

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop a Java application.

When I use debug, I can't debug with `step into`, `over`, or `out (trace)`. Why can't I do this?

< [image]The debug screen >

Comment: In general, there is no reason why you can't debug with **step into**, etc. using eclipse on a mac. Your situation is not generic but rather specific to your setup, the code in question, etc. We will need other information to be able to help you. This is a very poor quality question as it stands. I recommend that you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you get down voted out of existence. Good luck!

Comment: The good news for you is that Java is plateform independant. There is nothing wrong with your Mac. What kind of application you are writting, and how you debug it as there are many different possible setups for debugging.

Comment: I debug the java BST program, but when I debug it doesn't light up the step into button. I think it's about general setting.

Comment: It would be great if you can share a bit more of details on your setup. You cannot use step into/over/out by explicitly clicking on the icon in the Eclipse debug view ? Or you cannot use functional keys ?

Comment: I can use function key. However, It just doesn't appear on the bar.

Comment: @InkyuPark, can you please describe steps how do you attempt to debug your application ?

Comment: when I debug in window, it doesn't matter what I program it debug from top to bottom and I can manually step into every steps, but on mac, I can't even click the step into button, because it is not on, I want to figure out turned on "step into" button

Comment: @InkyuPark, can you setup a breakpoint at the first line of code to be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

The debugging buttons are not available because you are not currently debugging your code. They will become available only when your code stops on a breakpoint.